# till then vs until then

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

> Mohan said that he had been in London for two months but **until then/till then** he had not time to visit the water.

Is there any difference between *until then* and *till then*?

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/9356/3281, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6989/what-is-the-difference-between-till-and-until

Comment: Oh, what a difficult question!  *Till* doesn't sound very good at all in that particular sentence…

Comment: `'til` (a truncation of until) is sometimes also used in the same context

Comment: @Timmy *'Til* is simply a nonstandard spelling of *till*.

Comment: `till` is bizarre in writing. Much more colloquial, extremely informal. Would only see in writing on e.g. a pub window '8 till late!'

Comment: That's demonstrably false—check any written corpus for *till* and you'll find no shortage of examples.

Comment: Incidentally, `[...] he had not had time [...]` would be better.

Answer (score 4):

To add to Farooq's answer I'd say that **till** is slightly less formal than **until**.

In a formal announcement, **until** will be used more often:

> Appeals are registered until 5 p.m.

Answer (score 1):

They both mean the same thing. You have a choice between "until then" and "till then".  For example,

> Goodbye until then

or

> Goodbye till then

"Until then" is more common though.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between "until" and "till". You can use either until then or till then in the said sentence.

"Till" is more common in conversation.

Answer (score 1):

It's a common misconception that "till" (or "til") is an informal, shortened version of "until." Actually, till came first (check a reliable dictionary). If you want to avoid pedantic know-it-alls who don't actually know it all, it's safest to use "until," but there's nothing wrong with "til."